# Privilege level on a Cisco switch

Tags: cisco, switch, mirror

I'm just wondering, do you need to have a certain privilege level to set up a SPAN port on a Cisco switch? if so, what minimum level is required to set up a SPAN port?

I have no networking experience, so I'm not sure if this is a dumb question or not. I just need a answer as I'm working on a tool to interact with a switch, and this came to mind.

Comment: You need to be able to get to confuigre mode, which usually requires level 15 access.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i'm creating a tool for college that will allow users to set up span ports on a switch, so they have a user interface that will require them to enter in  there login details and then they can set the sources port and destination port per session

Comment: A organization big enough to need your tool will likely use TACACS to control access to switches.  It's easier to control access there than by configuring privilege levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no privilege level which specifically allows users to change only monitor port.

You need to make a view ([Role-Based CLI Access](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_usr_cfg/configuration/15-e/sec-usr-cfg-15-e-book/sec-role-base-cli.html#GUID-277FCB86-F32B-4CFB-9347-3D016F26ED2C)) which only allows a specific command, and assign it to the privileges:

> **SUMMARY STEPS**
>
> 1. enable view
> 2. configure terminal
> 3. parser view *view-name* [inclusive]
> 4. secret [0 | 5] *encrypted-password*
> 5. commands *parser-mode* {exclude | include-exclusive | include} [all] [interface *interface-name* | *command*]
> 6. end
> 7. enable [*privilege-level* | *view view-name*]
> 8. show parser view all